# Double Agenda card

Tags: fluxx

In Fluxx, if you play the "Double Agenda" rule this allows for two goals in play. If the Double Agenda card is removed by an action how do you deal with the two goals in play? Does the person who played the action to remove Double Agenda decide which "extra" goal to remove or do both goals stay in play?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you play a card that removes the double agenda rule you then get to choose which of the goals to remove and which one to keep.

Comment: Thank you for the response Joe. Turns out I have the original version that does not explain that. The newer versions changed the wording on the card which makes it clear what to do.